# Disable webclient ssl validation springboot 2.0.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, spring-webflux

On springboot 2.1 you can disable webclient ssl validation using snippet below, but how do you do this on springboot 2.0? Where the ReactorClientHttpConnector does not have this constructor that accpets the HttpClient, instead it has the constructor below

```
public ReactorClientHttpConnector(Consumer<? super HttpClientOptions.Builder> clientOptions) {
        this.httpClient = HttpClient.create(clientOptions);
    }
```

Snipppet below works on 2.1 but not on 2.0

```
SslContext context = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
            .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
            .build();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(t -> t.sslContext(context));
WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
```

Answer (score 1):

The api evolved a bit between 2.0 and 2.1. Find below a sample that works with 2.0.4:

```java
package com.example.webclienttest;

import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.util.InsecureTrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

public class WebClientTest {

  @Test
  public void test() throws SSLException {
    SslContext context = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
        .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(builder -> builder.sslContext(context)))
        .build();
    String stringMono = webClient.get().uri("https://expired.badssl.com/").retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class).block();
    System.out.println(stringMono);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that was a life saver